# How to find repeating sequences of a particular length in a list?

Tags: python

I have a *very* long list of strings. I have to find out if a sequence of *n* consecutive strings is repeating in the list.

I have looked up for other answers in detecting such sequences. However, most of them focus on detecting a continuously repeating **single** known sequence. In this case, their can be different sequences repeating with random strings in between.

For example:

```
long_list = ['execve','brk','getpid','time','read','write','exit','read','call','execve','brk','getpid','read','write','exit']
```

If n=3, the algorithm should output something like this:

```
{['execve','brk','getpid']:2,['read','write','exit']:2}
```

I have looked a lot if such a question has been previously answered but I could not find anything relevant. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: lists are unhashable and cannot be used as dictionary keys

Comment: Can you suggest another way to store the strings then? I think this would be quite a common problem. I have come back to programming after a long time as I generally work on hardware design using Verilog. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You could use tuples

Comment: You cannot use a list as a dictionary key, but you *can* use a [tuple](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#restrictions-on-dictionary-keys) (since they are immutable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?
Now checking if the occurences is more common than 1.

```
from collections import Counter

long_list = ['execve','brk','getpid','time','read','write','exit','read','call','execve','brk','getpid','read','write','exit']

def find_length_n(n):
    matches = []
    for idx, word in enumerate(long_list):
        tmp_string = long_list[idx:idx+n]
        matches.append(str(tmp_string))

    for key, val in Counter(matches).items():
        if val >= 2:
            print(key, val)

find_length_n(3)
```

will output:

```
['execve', 'brk', 'getpid'] 2
['read', 'write', 'exit'] 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to solve the problem. Will try it on my large dataset in some time!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this, perhaps?

```
 long_list.count('execve')
 2
```